# How to Deal with Hidden Element without Removing it - updating DOM length when Element hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I have a list of brand names  looking like this:

[image]

each element has a border-bottom style and I used the below code to remove border-bottom style when there are less than 5 elements and it works perfectly until you make a search and some of these elements are hidden. The problem is because even **display = 'none';** doesn't remove the elements from DOM. According to DOM, its length is the same so even there is one element and others are hidden border style is there. (img below code)

```
&:nth-child(5n+1):nth-last-child(-n+5), &:nth-child(5n+1):nth-last-child(-n+5) ~ .brands__list-item {
  @apply lg:border-b-0;
}
```

[image]

Removing elements from DOM instead of hiding works, but I need these elements later so I can't remove them. I want elements to have a border If a row has more than 5 elements.  How can I tackle this issue of hidden elements? Open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any exact property to use it, but here are some tricks you can use.
Just put the hidden element in a class and style it with `display:none`.

After adding that class, just use:

```
length2=DOM.classList.contains('classWithHiddenProp');
totalLength_of_DOM = totalLength - length2;
```

Comment: I updated your post to use code highlighting (and changed the answer to markdown). See help here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Okay you deleted the edit, nvm.

Comment: @ShivamSharma Oh no worries, it works with `<br>` as you did. I'll format the question again so you can see the difference - looks much cleaner. The help page is for you to read.

Comment: @Shivam Sharma Thanks for your reply!! your logic helped me to solve my problem.